# react-spring, animate list items individually

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have a component that renders a dynamic list. I wan't to delay every item individually, so that every items gets rendered with a delay relative to the previous item.
How would I achieve this in react-spring?

Here is the code so far:

```
  const transitions = useTransition(banks, bank => bank.bic, {
    opacity: 0,
    to: { opacity: 1 }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) =>
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          <Bank bank={item} />
        </animated.div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? the description sounds like you can do it with most of the available hooks, but we need to be certain to provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I should have read the docs better. There is a property called `trail`. To let each item animate with 50 ms delay relative to the previous, do:

```
const transitions = useTransition(banks, bank => bank.bic, {
    opacity: 0,
    to: { opacity: 1 },
    trail: 50
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) =>
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          <Bank bank={item} />
        </animated.div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Dude. this property is awesome. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You can add, a function into lifecycles object:

```
const transitions = useTransition(banks, (bank) => bank.bic, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: (item) => ({
      duration: 1000 * item.bic
    })
  });
```

Assuming that we can use `bic` as a incrementing value, the duration of each div will be progressive. Whether bic isn't a value to use for incrementing an other solution could to initialize a `counter` variable.

```
  let counter = 0;

  const transitions = useTransition(banks, (bank) => bank.bic, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: () => {
      counter++;
      return {
        duration: 1000 * counter
      };
    }
  });
```

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-list-items-individually-5uri8?file=/src/App.js:571-612

Comment: So cool that you can do this!  I would have assumed that you would need to call the hook in the child in order to have different values.